# How to ignore parent element's overflow:hidden in css

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a div element wrapping other div elements like so:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

I have other css rules that manage the dimensions of the outer div.  In my actual code,  I want to position the div#a exactly 10 px below the outer div.  However, I want div#b to still be cut off by the outer div's overflow:hidden.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can't do it like that, you need to take div#a out of the div with overflow:hidden.

Comment: `#a { position: relative; top: 10px; }`? or do you meant you want `#a` to be BELOW the bottom border of the outer div?

Comment: @MarcB - yes to I want to position #a below the bottom border of the outer div

Answer (score 148, accepted):

**Method 1**

A good way to do it is by setting the overflowing element to `position:fixed` (which will make it ignore the parent overflow), and then positioning it relative to the parent using this technique:

```
​.parent {
   position: relative;      
   .fixed-wrapper {
       position: absolute;         
       .fixed {
           position: fixed;
       }
   }
}
```

One caveat is that you cannot have any of the top,right,left,bottom properties set on the fixed element (they must all be default 'auto'). If you need to adjust the position slightly, you can do so using positive/negative margins instead.

**Method 2**

Another trick I recently discovered is to keep the `overflow:hidden` element with `position:static` and position the overriding element relative to a higher parent (rather than the `overflow:hidden` parent). Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/kv0bLpw8/

Comment: Method 1 works but may give weird results if the user scrolls the page. People landing on this answer: be sure to check out the JSFiddle under Method 2--it's very simple and works great!

Comment: Method 1 has one more caveat: you cannot have any transform set on the element which has overflow

Comment: Does not play nicely if container has scrollbar

Comment: Method 2 only works if you have no relatively positioned elements in between the leaf and the parent container... Doesn't work in my case where I can't actually override a style.

Comment: Method 2 is much better, because it works inside a scrollable container...

Comment: Interesting choice of 'ignore overflow' class name in fiddle.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need the child to have relative features like `width: 100%`. This is a massive flaw in HTML and CSS. Hard to believe it's still here in 2021.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#wrapper #insideDiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#wrapper #a {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: -40px;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a">AAA</div>
  <div id="insideDiv">
    <div id="b">BBB</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this code solves the specific problem by changing html structure, but do not ignore parent's element overflow

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most convenient way is to wrap your container `div` inside another `div` and set `position: relative` on the external div.

```css
.outer-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}

#a,
#b {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#a {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}

#b {
  background: red;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b">Cut off</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as people said, the element must be presented outside the parent in order to be not cropped. But you can do this with JavaScript to achieve the similar concept without having to change your actual markup:

```
function breakOverflow(elm) {
   var top = elm.offset().top;
   var left = elm.offset().left;
   elm.appendTo($('body'));
   elm.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: left+'px',
      top: top+'px',
      bottom: 'auto',
      right: 'auto',
      'z-index': 10000
   });
}
```

then pass the element you want to exclude from the cropping of its  parent:

```
breakOverflow($('#exlude-me'));
```

Comment: This method has disadvantages:
1. the element lose some styles (e.g. .parent .element { ... })
2. you can't rely on the ancestors in js code (e.g. $(element).closest('.js-parent'))