# Dropdown menu in scrollable element

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement a menu with submenus displayed in a dropdown.

The menu is composed of a header, the menu elements and a footer. To do so, I've used a simple `display: flex`on my parent element, two fixed sizes for the header and the footer and the rest for the content with `flex: 1`.

In order to manage the scroll in the content, I also have to set a `overflow: auto` on the content container. This causes the dropdown menu to show in the X axis scroll.

I'm not sure of what to do to fix this issue, I've tried to play with the `position: fixed`, [as mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013066/how-to-ignore-parent-elements-overflowhidden-in-css) but it doesn't work when I try to scroll.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lv7zv17/2/)'s the JSFiddle with the failed attempt to use a fixed position.

Current HTML template :

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-header">
      <h1>
        Header
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <ul>
        <li class="element" v-for="(element, index) in elements" :key="index" 
          @mouseenter="element.childrenVisible = true"
          @mouseleave="element.childrenVisible = false">
          <h2>
            {{ element.title }}
          </h2>
          <div class="children-wrapper" v-if="element.childrenVisible && element.children && element.children.length">
            <ul class="children">
              <li v-for="(child, childIndex) in element.children" :key="childIndex">
                <h3>
                  {{ child.title }}
                </h3>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-footer">
      <p>
        Footer..
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS only contains an instance of Vue and some test data, formatted like so :

```
{
  title: '1',
  childrenVisible: false,
  children: [{
    title: '1.1',
  }],
},
```

And the CSS (sass) looks like this :

```
.menu {
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 500px;
  background-color: #0a6e89;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .menu-header, .menu-footer {
    height: 70px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: #f9f8f2;
  }

  .menu-content {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
  }
}

.menu-content {  
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .element {
    position: relative;

    .children-wrapper {
      position: absolute;  
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
    }

    .children {
      position: fixed;
      background-color: #f9f8f2;
      border: 1px solid black;
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code, not just a link to it (which might someday break)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a method in @mouseenter rather than directly toggling the childrenVisible flag, you get an event passed to the parameter of the method.

This has screen coordinates and a reference to the parent element, and it's children.

```
@mouseenter="mouseEnter"

methods: {
  mouseEnter (event) {
    // adjust child position here
  }
}
```