# HTML Table: overflow hidden for horizontal scroll then blocks tooltip from showing outside of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

**TL;DR:** Cannot correctly position & display tooltips in a table due to `overflow: hidden`.

I have created a simple reproducible example of a table whose tooltips are not displaying as intended. The issue exists in part because the table requires `overflow: scroll` in order for the horizontal scroll of the table to work as intended. Here is an example:

```css
.gap {
  height: 50px
}

div.table { 
  max-width: 200px;

  overflow: scroll;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tr {
  display:flex;
}

.td, .th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}

.th {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #888888;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #555555;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

.tip0 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -60%;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 325px;
  min-width: 160px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tip1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 325px;
  min-width: 160px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tooltip:hover .tip0, .tooltip:hover .tip1 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='gap'>.</div>
<div class='table'>
  <div class='table-headers'>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='th tooltip'>
        Z
        <div class='tip0'>
          Heres the ToolTip For Column Z, getting cut off (bad)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='th'>Y</div>
      <div class='th tooltip'>
        X
        <div class='tip-wrapper'>
          <div class='tip1'>
            Heres the Tooltip For Column X, which doesn't stay at the top (bad)
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='th'>W</div>
      <div class='th'>V</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table-body'>
    <div class='tr'>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td stick'>A</div>
      <div class='td'>B</div>
      <div class='td'>C</div>
      <div class='td'>D</div>
      <div class='td'>E</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the table above, the `Z` and `X` header cells have tooltips that appear on, however. However, there are issues with both of these tooltips currently:

**Column Z:** Because of `overflow: hidden`, this tooltip is getting cut off. It is important that the table can scroll horizontally, so I cannot remove this `overflow` CSS property. However, its also important that the tooltip hovers above the top of the table, so as to not block the content of the table.

**Column X:** I tried this approach from [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013066/how-to-ignore-parent-elements-overflowhidden-in-css/22927412). Method 1. This allows the tooltip outside of the `overflow: hidden`. However, when I scroll this table vertically, the tooltip moves as well, which is not good. The tooltip should remain at the same height always, just above the top of the table.

I was hoping that this basic "tooltips inside the table headers" would work, but it isn't so far. Because of this, I am considering creating a separate tooltip `div` outside of the table's HTML, and using `onMouseOver()` and `onMouseOut()` handler functions to position the tooltip at the mouse location, and populate the tooltip with text. Maybe that is my only approach?

Comment: Why do you build a fake-table with divs and flex?

Comment: Has nothing to do with a table. Overflow hidden is a rendering context for its child elements. Why not set the tooltip to `position:fixed` and then position it based on the table cell's X/Y offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

You can mimic your table canvas with a sibling element, then use custom overflow properties on that child to achieve whatever effect you'd like:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  const tool = document.querySelector('.tooltip-canvas > tooltip')
  const toolEls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.table [tooltip]'))
  toolEls.forEach(t => {
    t.onmouseenter = _ => {
      tool.setAttribute('tooltip', t.getAttribute('tooltip'))
      tool.style.left = `${t.clientLeft}px`
      tool.style.top = `${t.clientTop - 2}px`
    }
    t.onmouseleave = _ => tool.removeAttribute('tooltip')
  })
})
```

```css
.gap {
  height: 50px
}

.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table-wrap > .tooltip-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.table-wrap > .tooltip-canvas > tooltip {
  content: attr(tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 325px;
  min-width: 160px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: opacity .25s;
}
.table-wrap > .tooltip-canvas > tooltip[tooltip] {
  opacity: 1;
}

.table-wrap > .tooltip-canvas > tooltip:before {
  content: attr(tooltip)
}

div.table { 
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tr {
  display:flex;
}

.td, .th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}

.th {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #888888;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #555555;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='gap'>.</div>
<section class='table-wrap'>
  <div class='table'>
    <div class='table-headers'>
      <div class='tr'>
        <div class='th' tooltip='Heres the ToolTip For Column Z, getting cut off (bad)'>
          Z
        </div>
        <div class='th'>Y</div>
        <div class='th' tooltip='Heres the Tooltip For Column X, which doesn&spquot;t stay at the top (bad)'>
          X
        </div>
        <div class='th'>W</div>
        <div class='th'>V</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='table-body'>
      <div class='tr'>
      </div>
      <div class='tr'>
        <div class='td stick'>A</div>
        <div class='td'>B</div>
        <div class='td'>C</div>
        <div class='td'>D</div>
        <div class='td'>E</div>
      </div>
      <div class='tr'>
        <div class='td'>F</div>
        <div class='td'>G</div>
        <div class='td'>H</div>
        <div class='td'>I</div>
        <div class='td'>J</div>
      </div>
      <div class='tr'>
        <div class='td'>F</div>
        <div class='td'>G</div>
        <div class='td'>H</div>
        <div class='td'>I</div>
        <div class='td'>J</div>
      </div>
      <div class='tr'>
        <div class='td'>F</div>
        <div class='td'>G</div>
        <div class='td'>H</div>
        <div class='td'>I</div>
        <div class='td'>J</div>
      </div>
      <div class='tr'>
        <div class='td'>F</div>
        <div class='td'>G</div>
        <div class='td'>H</div>
        <div class='td'>I</div>
        <div class='td'>J</div>
      </div>
      <div class='tr'>
        <div class='td'>F</div>
        <div class='td'>G</div>
        <div class='td'>H</div>
        <div class='td'>I</div>
        <div class='td'>J</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <aside class='tooltip-canvas'>
    <tooltip></tooltip>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Comment: This is the only answer where the tooltip remains at the top of the table when I scroll vertically down the table. The `overflow: hidden` property is very hard to get around for child elements, and placing the tooltip outside of the table seems like the right idea.

Comment: If this worked for you @Canovice, could you mark the answer as completed?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `.tip-wrapper` element on ***tip0***, if you add this and set the `top` position of `.tip-wrapper` using `calc()` to ***-(th height) - (top threshold in rem)*** in this case `calc(-50px - 1.5rem)` then the problem is solved and you have the tooltip placed on top of the table.

You could use dynamic units in `th` height such as `vh`, `vmax`, `%`.
Additionally you would need some @media queries to `fine-tune` the position of the tooltip.

```
.td,
.th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 10%;
  height: 5vh;
}
.tip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-5vh - 1.5rem);
}
```

```css
.gap {
  height: 100px
}

div.table {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tr {
  display: flex;
}

.td,
.th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}

.th {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #888888;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #555555;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-50px - 1.5rem);
}

.tip0 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 325px;
  min-width: 160px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tip1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 325px;
  min-width: 160px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tooltip:hover .tip0,
.tooltip:hover .tip1 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='gap'>Gap</div>
<div class='table'>
  <div class='table-headers'>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='th tooltip'>
        Z
        <div class='tip-wrapper'>
          <div class='tip0'>
            Tip For Column Z is a long tip with enough text to overflow above the page top
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='th'>Y</div>
      <div class='th tooltip'>
        X
        <div class='tip-wrapper'>
          <div class='tip1'>
            Tip For Column Z is a long tip with enough text to overflow above the page top
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='th'>W</div>
      <div class='th'>V</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table-body'>
    <div class='tr'>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td stick'>A</div>
      <div class='td'>B</div>
      <div class='td'>C</div>
      <div class='td'>D</div>
      <div class='td'>E</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you scroll vertically down this table, the table header does not stay at the top of the table. that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the top value in tip0:

```
.tip0 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 325px;
  min-width: 160px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```css
.gap {
  height: 100px
}

div.table { 
  max-width: 200px;

  overflow: scroll;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tr {
  display:flex;
}

.td, .th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
}

.th {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #888888;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #555555;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

.tip0 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 325px;
  min-width: 160px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tip1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 325px;
  min-width: 160px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tooltip:hover .tip0, .tooltip:hover .tip1 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='gap'>Gap</div>
<div class='table'>
  <div class='table-headers'>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='th tooltip'>
        Z
        <div class='tip0'>
          Tip For Column Z is a long tip with enough text to overflow above the page top
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='th'>Y</div>
      <div class='th tooltip'>
        X
        <div class='tip-wrapper'>
          <div class='tip1'>
            Tip For Column Z is a long tip with enough text to overflow above the page top
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='th'>W</div>
      <div class='th'>V</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table-body'>
    <div class='tr'>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td stick'>A</div>
      <div class='td'>B</div>
      <div class='td'>C</div>
      <div class='td'>D</div>
      <div class='td'>E</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tr'>
      <div class='td'>F</div>
      <div class='td'>G</div>
      <div class='td'>H</div>
      <div class='td'>I</div>
      <div class='td'>J</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the tooltip to hover above-top over the table, not below / inside of the table.

Comment: Oh I see you want tool tip to float above the table ?

Comment: yes, so it does not block the content in the first few rows of the table.

Comment: Check Now and see if it's what you want

Comment: The tooltip for column `Z` now behaves in the same way as the tooltip for column `X`. Unfortunately, when I horizontally scroll down the table, the tooltip moves as well, whereas I need the tooltip to remain floating atop the table, even during vertical scroll.

I appreciate the help so far but this is not what I need either.

Comment: I got your point now. I assume the distance from top is correct the thing which is left is that you want it to float while scrolling and not move.

Comment: Yeah. The original `top: -60%` is roughly where I want the tooltip to be positioned always. Maybe even a bit higher up, but around there.

Answer (score 0):

> For tooltip above the table

Remove top attribute and change the position attribute in .tip0 as below

```
.tip0 {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        margin: -56px -4px;
        z-index: 1;
        max-width: 325px;
        min-width: 160px;
        color: #333333;
        text-align: left;
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

And add margin in .tip1 as below

```
.tip1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    margin: -56px -4px;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 325px;
    min-width: 160px;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: left;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

> For displaying tooltip within table

Add margin attribute as below inside .tip0 and .tip1 to keep tooltip inside table.

```
margin: -17px 0px;
```

and
remove top attribute from .tip0

Comment: Similar to many other answers, this results in a tooltop that does not stay at the top of the table. Rather, as I scroll down the table, the tooltip scrolls down as well. It does not stay at the top. I appreciate the help but this is not a solution.