# adding overflow scroll removes pseudo element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a tooltip here where I'm displaying a list of emails that are tracked and It is required to have a certain height. so, I have added overflow. if I'm doing that I'm losing the speech bubble which is placed as pseudo-element. uncomment the line which I have stated in css. I had looked into the similar StackOverflow questions regarding the similar issue but they don't work in my case .

here's [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/3015weLd/)

```css
.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip_container {
    background: white;
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
    /* uncomment to see the change */
    /* overflow-y: scroll;  */
}
.tooltip_container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}

.tooltip_container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.tooltip_container::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #dbdeb5;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.track_event img {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
#track_events {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #dbdeb5;
}

#track_events_list {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.track_event {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 1rem;
    align-items: baseline;
    margin: 0 15px;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.mail_viewer_info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-start;
    text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <div class="tooltip_container">
        <section id="track_events"></section>
        <section id="track_events_list">
            <div class="track_event">
                <img
                    src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/535/535244.png"
                    alt=""
                />

                <div class="mail_viewer_info">
                    <h3 class="tracked_email">elon@spacex.com</h3>

                    <div class="event_info">
                        <span>22m <span> . </span>opened email </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="track_event">
                <img
                    src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/535/535244.png"
                    alt=""
                />

                <div class="mail_viewer_info">
                    <h3 class="tracked_email">elon@spacex.com</h3>

                    <div class="event_info">
                        <span>22m <span> . </span>opened email </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="track_event">
                <img
                    src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/535/535244.png"
                    alt=""
                />

                <div class="mail_viewer_info">
                    <h3 class="tracked_email">elon@spacex.com</h3>

                    <div class="event_info">
                        <span>22m <span> . </span>opened email </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is that once you apply `overflow: scroll;`, elements outside the bounding box are hidden implictly (as with `overflow: hidden;`). You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013066/how-to-ignore-parent-elements-overflowhidden-in-css) question to see how to work around that, but you'll most likely have to change your markup structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use overflow-y in `#track_events_list`

```
#track_events_list {
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```css
.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip_container {
    background: white;
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 10%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 1px rgba(0, 0 0, 0.34);
    /* uncomment to see the change */
    /*overflow-y: scroll; */

}
.tooltip_container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}

.tooltip_container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.tooltip_container::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #dbdeb5;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.track_event img {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
#track_events {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #dbdeb5;
}

#track_events_list {
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.track_event {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 1rem;
    align-items: baseline;
    margin: 0 15px;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.mail_viewer_info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-start;
    text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <div class="tooltip_container">
        <section id="track_events"></section>
        <section id="track_events_list">
            <div class="track_event">
                <img
                    src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/535/535244.png"
                    alt=""
                />

                <div class="mail_viewer_info">
                    <h3 class="tracked_email">elon@spacex.com</h3>

                    <div class="event_info">
                        <span>22m <span> . </span>opened email </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="track_event">
                <img
                    src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/535/535244.png"
                    alt=""
                />

                <div class="mail_viewer_info">
                    <h3 class="tracked_email">elon@spacex.com</h3>

                    <div class="event_info">
                        <span>22m <span> . </span>opened email </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="track_event">
                <img
                    src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/535/535244.png"
                    alt=""
                />

                <div class="mail_viewer_info">
                    <h3 class="tracked_email">elon@spacex.com</h3>

                    <div class="event_info">
                        <span>22m <span> . </span>opened email </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```