# Show dropdown outside of the scrollable container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a simple example demonstrating the *issue* I'm facing. An example code shows a dropdown inside a container. When the dropdown is opened a scrollbar appears. [Example code.](https://jsfiddle.net/puLh0qj2/)

I know that an easy solution would be to set `overflow: visible` on the container element but I need a scrollbar on the container.
In the real world, this example would be a modal with a form inside which is pretty big so we need a scrollbar. One of the form items is dropdown which is the last element in the list so it would be great if we could get this to go outside of the modal.

**Update**

Removing `position: relative` from the parent fixes one part of the issue but introduces another one. Here is an [example code](https://jsfiddle.net/hcxvpgm4/3/)

The issue is if the scrollbar appears when you scroll the modal, the dropdown overlay doesn't follow the dropdown button.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the position relative on the parent.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function toggle() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown {
  /*position: relative;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="toggle()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>foo bar baz foo bar baz</h3>
<h3>foo bar baz foo bar baz</h3>
<h3>foo bar baz foo bar baz</h3>
```

Comment: Yep, this fixes one issue and that is the overflow problem but introduces another one. [Example code](https://jsfiddle.net/hcxvpgm4/3/)

The issue is if the scrollbar appears when you scroll the modal, the dropdown overlay doesn't follow the dropdown button.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the changes I've made [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hkzxtrje/33/). By adding an additional wrapper container around the dropdown container with the `position: absolute;` we should be able to maintain the behavior that you have been intending to keep, and by setting the `position` as `fixed` on the actual dropdown content wrapper element we should be able to override the overflow property from the `.container` div element.

Hope that helps!

PS: Got some inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22927412/12915265) post which might explain it a bit better than I could.